# Close current browser in other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below HTML, which redirects the page and closes the current window

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="close_window()">
```

I tested it, it can redirect page OR close window only, but cannot do both at the same time, that means after redirecting to another page, it does not close the window. Could you advise how to make it close the window after redirect?

Comment: You need to show what `close_window()` does. Also, think about how you are going to know which window to close, and specify that in your question too. Do you want to change the location of the current window, then close it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Javascript to do this. Use window.close():

close();
Note: the current window is implied. This is equivalent:

window.close();
or you can specify a different window.

So:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

with HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
or:

<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

You return false here to prevent the default behavior for the event. Otherwise the browser will attempt to go to that URL (which it obviously isn't).

Now the options on the window.confirm() dialog box will be OK and Cancel (not Yes and No). If you really want Yes and No you'll need to create some kind of modal Javascript dialog box.

Comment: the below code is only close window , how to redirect it to google first , then close the window ? thanks 

<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
or:

<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>

Comment: or load a URL and then close the window , how to do it ? thanks

Comment: may be I re-phase my question

Comment: I have the below HTML, which redirects the page to google.com and run close_window to exit the current window 

"<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="close_window()">"

I tested it, it can redirect page OR close window only, but cannot do both at the same time, that means after redirecting to another page, it does not close the window. 

Could you advise if I want the window redirect to another page ( www.google.com ) first , then wait 10 second , then close this redirected page ( window ) automatically , how to make it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to try window.open for this:

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
               testWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com");
               setTimeout(function() { testWindow.close() },5000);
            }

            test();
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: hi shemy  , sorry , this is not what I want

Comment: hi shemy , your method seems open new windows , I just want to use the current window